# JSON with MultiValueMap on Java

Tags: java, json

I Would like to build a JSON like this:

```
{
  "Id": "33396",
  "Actions": [
    {
      "Key": "5",
      "Value": "Test"
    },
    {
      "Key": "6",
      "Value": "Test 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using MultiValueMap and that's my code:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

map.add("Id","33396");
```

I don't know how to implement the Actions List on my code

I did this and worked but I think it's repetitive

MultiValueMap map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
MultiValueMap mapActions0 = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
MultiValueMap mapActions1 = new LinkedMultiValueMap();

```
    //Id
    map.add("Id","33396");

    //Actions
    mapActions0.add("Key","5");
    mapActions0.add("Value","Test");
    mapActions1.add("Key","6");
    mapActions1.add("Value","Test 2");

    map.put("AcoesVideo",Arrays.asList(mapActions0,mapActions));
```

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604319/jackson-json-deserialize-commons-multimap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HashMap` and use a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` do this

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> actions = new HashMap<>();

actions.put("5", "test");
actions.put("6", "test2");

map.put("33396", actions);
```

Comment: But where will "Key" and "Value" be? I need them on JSON. Thank's a lot

Comment: @MarcosViníciusCarvalho You have no control of this? Because ideally you don't need to do that is evident from the structure. Also you understand in your structure when you are using a map and keep adding "Key" something and then value something, no matter how many times you do this your map will only contain one key and one value, because map the key has to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, Object> innerMap1 = Maps.newHashMap();
innerMap1.put("Key", "5");
innerMap1.put("Value", "Test");

HashMap<String, Object> innerMap2 = Maps.newHashMap();
innerMap2.put("Key", "6");
innerMap2.put("Value", "Test 2");

ArrayList<Object> list = Lists.newArrayList();
list.add(innerMap1);
list.add(innerMap2);

HashMap<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("ID", "33396");
map.put("Actions", list);

System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(map));
```