# Error when using RestTemplate - problem with deserialization of object with Apache Commons Multimap

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, apache-commons, multimap

I am trying to retreive using RestTemplate object from service.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<BusinessPartnerRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);

    ResponseEntity<Analysis> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Analysis.class);
```

Unfortunately I got Exception each time. This is the exception:

Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.abb.bttr.validator.Analysis] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]

I know that this is general exception and mapper return it every time there will be any Exception.

So I found real cause:
Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]

My Analysis object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiValueMap;

    @JacksonXmlRootElement
    public class Analysis {
        private Boolean error = false;
        @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = MapSerializer.class)
        private MultiMap<String, String> errorDetails = new MultiValueMap<>();

        //getter, setters, constructors, equals and hashcode
    }
```

Do you know a way to deserialize ApacheCommons MultiMap in quick way? I can use guava, but I don't want to add Guava library just for Multimap.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604319/jackson-json-deserialize-commons-multimap) can help you ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I am using RestTemplate, not plain ObjectMapper and also my Multimap is inside object. For Guava there is only need to register module for mapper:
    messageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule());
For Commons Multimap I can't find anything similar on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instruct which type you want to use for `MultiMap` by using `SimpleModule` class. See below code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiValueMap;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MultiMap<String, String> multiMap = new MultiValueMap<>();
    multiMap.put("a", "AA");
    multiMap.put("a", "AAA");
    multiMap.put("b", "B");
    multiMap.put("b", "BB");

    SimpleModule collections4Module = new SimpleModule();
    collections4Module.addAbstractTypeMapping(MultiMap.class, MultiValueMap.class);

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonMapper.registerModule(collections4Module);

    String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(multiMap);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(jsonMapper.readValue(json, MultiMap.class));
  }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"a":["AA","AAA"],"b":["B","BB"]}
{a=[[AA, AAA]], b=[[B, BB]]}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for! It works, thank you.

Comment: Looks like when mapper is doing read, it incorrectly deserialize object... It make MultiMap with key and as value put ArrayList of values instead of put values into ArrayList. Have you any idea for workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of Apache conman APP you can utilize the Spring predicated Map. 
Import verbalization like below.

```
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
```

And utilize the multi Map like below.

```
 MultiValueMap<String, Integer> multiValueMap=new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have model in separate maven project and there is no Spring, so I don't think adding Spring for only MultiMap will be a good idea.